# power apps tree control with expand nd collapse functionality in canvas app

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, sharepoint-list, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to create a tree view in powerapps. can someone please guide me on this,I am refering the below link, and the second example but the expand and collapse doesnot seem to work.
https://www.canviz.com/power-apps-tree-control/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your problem is solved. But I had a similar need, and followed the following link which had clear steps to follow and expand/collapse worked for me.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/nerdy-article-creating-powerapp-mobile-app-browse-structured-dagan/

Best regards,
Deb